# in aem in touch ui using sightly to a parsys component if i add some image or anything next parsys should be after that one not below it

Tags: aem, sightly

in aem in touch ui using sightly if I add a parsys component with some width(ex:30%) and after adding some component to it next parsys should come after that one not below of the previous component. How can I do that one?

Answer (score 1):

There is not something like "fixed-fluid layout" in AEM.

You should create a layout before drop the components, you can use column control to achieve this, take a look to the documentation: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/custom_columns.html